# How to attach a txt file to Jira using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to add the output of my Python code (which is a txt file) into Jira . Can someone please help me? I want a txt file to be added to Jira using Python

Comment: I think you also can ask your question in the Atlassian community. They may know  better how to integrate!

Comment: Thanks I will do